# straight line is distorted in distance eevee

Tags: texturing, distort

I made this simple scene so far: [image]

The middle line is perfectly straight. Somehow it gets distorted as you can see. This happens in the viewport, eevee rendering but not in cycles rendering. What is going on here?

The line is put via texturemask on the ground (just in case this matters)

Comment: What is the line made of?  Is it a texture applied to flat geometry or a series of modeled boxes?

Comment: It is a texture, I found out that by changing the texture interpolation it works. I don't even know what it is, you wanna explain?